# Magento 2.2.6 + Apache + varnish 4. seems url rewrite not working

Tags: apache, magento2, varnish

I am putting varnish cache in front of a magento 2.2.6 site which use just http.

After I configure ports and put the generated varnish.vcl in the /etc/varnish folder, I can see the front page, however 2 css files went missing (404). What's even worse is I cannot access any link, like /admin /menu /contents

It seems like the url rewrite is not working any longer. any clue how to solve/debug this?

thanks!

!!!!update after quite some time!!!!!
I solved this issue long while ago and did not get a good time to write a step by step tutorial. Luckily somebody else did it. See the link below:

https://komelin.com/articles/https-varnish/

In short, setting a synth status when the ip is foreign, and requesting for port 80 will solve the loop issue. Varnish should redirect this request to 443 (nginx). After this point, the work flow is the same as the described in the article above. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file in place?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin yes. The site fully functional when I switch back to apache and turn off varnish

Comment: I am just gonna leave it here. The issue is not really url rewrite, it is with the configuration of varnish and apache. I moved to Nginx to solve this issue, nginx will terminate https and fall back to http and varnish will serve http content to nginx.